# Auth0 stuck in callback

Tags: auth0

Used auth0 for my react project and it works fine at my local.

When i put my project to the server login page shows up, but after i try to login i get an error. 
`http://localhost:3000/callback?code=ZSaQ96OshsFfpBUN&state=q3KiPGbEPtIZ3UuSLd.KSbKjdXqk9-pD`

firefox says 
`unable to connect - cant establish a connection to localhost:3000` and on

chrome i got 
`this site can't be reached - localhost refused to connect`

I tried different callback urls on the auth0 side but nothing changed. I do not know exactly what to do actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your project isn't running on the same connection that you were locally. Make sure to change all the registered callbacks to their current locations when changing to a different deployment.